# Jelastic git-push-deploy not branch aware

Tags: github, continuous-integration, github-actions, jelastic

I used `git-push-deploy` add-on on Jelastic to automatically deploy updates to my PHP app from GitHub. I set up the add-on to take the updates from my main branch but it is taking updates from my development branch too.

As soon as I push updates to the development branch, the ROOT context updates and it again updates if I merge those updates to the main.

Is this the expected behaviour or is there anything extra to configure?

Link to `git-push-deploy` repo: https://github.com/jelastic-jps/git-push-deploy

Comment: Is this issue still relevant? It wasn't reproduced on our side. Did you contact your Hosting provider to solve the issue?

Comment: @Jelastic I retested the issue and I found that it is just updating the ROOT context every time I push an update to my repo no matter which branch it is. But it is not actually taking updates from other branches than the defined main branch. So, technically it doesn't cause any harm to the deployment and the issue is not fully relevant.